# SQL Syntax for 'If A does not exist in Query Return B, but if A does exist only return A'

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query that returns current and future revenue from a GLTable.  There are two posting types I need to return.  If Postingtype A does not exist then return postingtype B if postingtype A exists only return postingtype A. DB is MSSQL 2014.

I have tried several variations of below,

```
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM GLAccountPosting WHERE PostingType = 10) 
        )
        OR
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM GLAccountPosting WHERE PostingType = 14) 

        (;

WHERE 
postingtype in (14, 10)
AND
    (StartDateTime > '2019/07/01' AND postingtype = 10)
    OR
     (StartDateTime < '2019/07/01' AND postingtype = 14);

WHERE
    (StartDateTime > '2019/07/01' AND postingtype = 10 ) OR
    (StartDateTime < '2019/07/01' OR postingtype = 14);
```

Query Below(Truncated as it is very large):

```
SELECT 

prepay.Prepay,
Case When GAP.postingtype = 14 then isnull(sum(GAP.CreditValue),0) ELSE 0 end as CreditTodate,
Case When GAP.postingtype = 14 then prepay.Prepay -  isnull(sum(GAP.CreditValue),0) ELSE prepay.Prepay   end AS Balance,

GAP.PostingType


 FROM
GLAccountPosting AS GAP

    JOIN (SELECT 

                        SalesTransactions.BranchID,
                        Departments.DepartmentGUID,
                        SalesTransactions.SalesTransactionGUID,
                        SalesTransactionDetails.SalesTransactionLineGUID,
                        Sum(SalesTransactionDetails.Prepayvalue) AS Prepay



                 FROM   
                      intellimanager.dbo.SalesTransactionDetails
                      INNER JOIN  intellimanager.dbo.SalesTransactions ON SalesTransactionDetails.SalesTransactionGUID=SalesTransactions.SalesTransactionGUID
                      INNER JOIN  intellimanager.dbo.SalesTransactionLines ON SalesTransactionDetails.SalesTransactionLineGUID=SalesTransactionLines.SalesTransactionLineGUID
                      INNER JOIN  intellimanager.dbo.Departments on Departments.DepartmentGUID = SalesTransactionDetails.ItemDepartmentGUID
                      left  JOIN  intellimanager.dbo.BookingLinesDetails on BookingLinesDetails.BookinglinesDetailGUID = SalesTransactionDetails.BookinglinesDetailGUID
                      LEFT JOIN  intellimanager.dbo.BookingLines on BookingLines.BookingLineGUID = BookingLinesDetails.BookingLineGUID

                 WHERE  
                      (
                            SalesTransactionDetails.AccrualStatus = 1 OR SalesTransactionDetails.AccrualStatus=2 -- 1 = reversed, 2 = deferred
                      ) AND
                        SalesTransactions.PostingDateTime < DateAdd(day,1,'2019/04/27') and
                        SalesTransactionDetails.BranchID IN (SELECT number FROM dbo.InzSplitInt(1)) AND-- selected branch 
                        SalesTransactionDetails.AccrualType = 2 AND  --- sessions only
                        SalesTransactionDetails.PrepayValue <> 0 AND
                        isnull(SalesTransactionLines.CreditSalesTransactionLineGUID,0x0) = 0x0  and -- remove credited lines      
                        SalesTransactions.status = 1 and -- remove not finalised and cancelled invoices
                        BookingLinesDetails.ItemType = 1 and  
                      (BookingLinesDetails.BookingDetailProgress not in (2,4) or 
                        (
                            BookingLinesDetails.BookingDetailProgress in (2,4) and SalesTransactionDetails.AccrualStatus <> 1)
                        ) 
                        and
                        (   
                            BookingLinesDetails.CalendarLinkGUID is null or 
                            (BookingLinesDetails.CalendarLinkGUID is not null and BookingLinesDetails.StartDateTime >= '2019/01/01'
                            )
                        ) 

                         -- include all sales tran details that are for bookings in the future
                         -- whether they have been completed or not and whether they have 

                        GROUP BY 
                            SalesTransactions.BranchID,
                            SalesTransactions.SalesTransactionGUID,
                            SalesTransactionDetails.SalesTransactionLineGUID,
                            Departments.DepartmentGUID,
                            BookingLinesDetails.StartDateTime) As prepay on prepay.SalesTransactionLineGUID = GAP.SalesTransactionLineGUID
                        JOIN salestransactionlines stl on stl.salestransactionlineguid = gap.salestransactionlineguid

                        LEFT JOIN salestransactiondetails sd on sd.SalesTransactiondetailGUID = GAP.SalesTransactiondetailGUID


where 
        GAP.ItemType = 1



group by


GAP.GLPostingDescription,
GAP.postingtype,
GAP.FormattedGLAccountCode,
prepay.Prepay,
GAP.PostingType
```

The results I need are:

```
Prepaid   Current Future  postingtype
26.90     0.00    26.90   10
215.20  215.20     0.00   14
```

Each line would potentially have both Postingtype 10 and 14 but I only want to see one at a time.  If both show up for the same transaction it makes the totals inaccurate.

Comment: If you want only one row, then use `select top (1)`.

Comment: The report can return over 5000 rows.

Comment: . . " If Postingtype A does not exist then return postingtype B if postingtype A exists only return postingtype A. "  That statement and your sample data suggest that you want only one row.

Comment: `select top(1) with ties ... order by row_number() over (partition by<transaction identity> order by postingtype)`

Comment: Apologies perhaps I misunderstood, I only want one row for each transaction yes.  it has to be either posting type A and if that does not exist in the query then I want Posting type B.

Comment: thank you Serg, but that only gives me type 10 in the query when it should have only type 14.

Comment: `.. order by postingtype DESC` if 14 is top priority over 10

Comment: Thank you so much Serg that worked fantastically,  never heard of syntax with ties.  I have spent weeks on the whole report and this was the last bit.  thanks again.  Not sure how I mark your comment as correct

Comment: @sabbegk, If performance matters, it was actually better to use a CTE with `ROW_NUMBER()` and a `WHERE` on the outermost `SELECT` to filter for the rows wich git a row-number of `1`. Serg's query is very *pretty* and I really like its slickness, but the sorting will be performed twice, quite a drawback with larger sets...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```html
DECLARE @t TABLE (TransactionID INT)
DECLARE @p TABLE (PostingType CHAR(1), TransactionID INT)

INSERT INTO @t
(TransactionID)
VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3)

INSERT INTO @p
(PostingType, TransactionID)
VALUES
('A', 1),
('B', 1),
('A', 2),
('B', 3)

SELECT t.TransactionID FROM @t t
WHERE
 EXISTS
  (
   SELECT 1 FROM @p p
   PIVOT  
   (  
   COUNT(p.PostingType)  
   FOR p.PostingType IN ([A], [B])  
   ) sq
   WHERE
    (
     ([A] = 0 AND [B] > 0) --Postingtype A does not exist then return postingtype B
     OR ([A] > 0 AND [B] = 0) --If postingtype A exists only return postingtype A
    )
    AND sq.TransactionID = t.TransactionID
  )
```

Comment: Thank you, I did try this, not exactly sure where to put it in my code, My knowledge of using temp tables etc is limited, but I got this error when running: (3 rows affected)
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 11
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: This error message "binary data would be truncated" means content is to large for number of allowed characters in column. Perhaps you can post a script that inserts sample data into a #temp table and your current query.